Can I use the MARRS function as alternative VARMAX model for forecasting
I want to forecast my data by R and using varmax model multivariate time series , i have this code i want to chck is it true ?
I check arima and arimax code after tht i found var and varx code , so i need VAARMAX for my master digree i have the fisrt time working on VARMAX model , I dont know the code from above write or i should use another code like varmax function , actualy I treid but I coildnot found the function?`install.packages("MARSS")
library(MARSS

Looks like your question is missing the code you said you were going to share.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
